# Как остановить брутфорс сайта на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Постоянно пытаются взломать сайт на wordpress.
Что сделал:

- поставил плагин Limit Login Attempts, блокирующий после первого же неправильного логина
- переименовал wp-login.php
- заблокировал папку wp-admin в .htaccess: Deny from all

Все равно постоянно приходят отчеты от плагина:

> 1 неудачных попыток авторизации (1 изоляция(ий)) с адреса IP: 186.202.153.141
>   Последняя попытка пользователя: admin

Каким образом обходят отсутствие wp-login.php и блокировку wp-admin ?

Comment: могут, например, через [XML-RPC](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/10/brute-force-amplification-attacks-against-wordpress-xmlrpc.html)

Comment: Во, спасибо! Отключил с помощью плагина XML-RPC и перестали

Comment: с этим надо поаккуратнее - этот файл может использоваться другими плагинами, можно ограничить число отправляемых через xml-rpc логинов до минимального - возможно, лучше будет именно такое решение использовать. Хотя если у вас точно нет таких плагинов, то можно было вообще грохнуть этот файл (главное не забыть о нем при следующем обновлении))

Answer (score 1):

- Можно воспользоваться плагином [iThemes Security](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/). В нем можно
  настроить доступ только с какого-нибудь определенного ip, банить за
  неправильный логин более n раз и прочее. Весьма полезно то, что можно
  просто изменить адрес логина с `wp-admin` на что-то свое. Впрочем там
  много различных добротных функций, подробных статей, где все описаны,
  можно найти достаточно.
- Также можно воспользовать самый простой способ - плагин [Clef](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wpclef/). У
  него в настройках можно запретить логин через пароль для
  администратора и оставить возможным логин только через приложение
  clef на смартфоне. Даже если пароль от админа будет введен верный,
  залогиниться можно будет только через подключенное приложение clef на
  смартфоне.
- Ну и традиционно можно капчу [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) подключить просто.
  Плагинов, автоматизирующих процесс, также можно найти немало.

Answer (score 0):

1. Сделай двойную авторизацию с помощью Htaccess и htpasswd, как это оформить все есть в инете.
2. смени адрес админки
3. поставь капчу на авторизацию
4. сам файл wp-config.php можешь переместить на папку домена, выше `public_html` - он будет читаться движком, но с инета его уже не достанешь ;)

Comment: Как уже писал - админка заблокирована через htaccess т.е. всем 403 выдает. Помогло отключение XML-RPC